# document.write() after window.onload

Tags: javascript, html

I have some html+java+style codes which required to be loaded only after the whole page is loaded. However, if I use document.write() in window.onload method, it completely clear the whole page and write the new codes.

How can I avoid this? Any other workarounds? Thank you so much.

Comment: document.write will start from the clean slate! what do you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: Why are you using `document.write` in the first place? It's a legacy and outdated method everyone should forget. In short, it's not to be used in any modern page.

Comment: You can use innerHTML or appendChild (dom methods) if you want to write.